# Playing video using versaplayer in ios app

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying to use Versaplayer framework to Play a video using it , i used this code

`@IBOutlet weak var playerView: VersaPlayerView! @IBOutlet weak var controls: VersaPlayerControls override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad() playerView.use(controls: controls) if let url = URL.init(string: "http://rmcdn.2mdn.net/Demo/html5/output.mp4") { let item = VersaPlayerItem(url: url) playerView.set(item: item) } }` 
But when i add this `playerView.use(controls: controls)`

I have an error because all of controls are nil ! It seems that I misunderstood of how can i add controls right.

Can anyone help me to figure out how can i add controls to my video player.
And here’s the repo it have a deep details ,

https://github.com/josejuanqm/VersaPlayer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to correct. I think the outlet connection you took is not in right way.

Step 1:
Copy the versacontrol view from example provided by them and add it to your storyboard.

Step 2:
Connect your outlet to the view you added in your storyboard.

I am attaching images please check.

[image]

[image]

[image]